# Why the program output is not displaying each string separately after getting UpperCased?

Tags: java, string, uppercase

the program is written for converting every first letter of the word to UpperCase

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i;
        String toBeCapped="";

        String str[] ={"This is a ball","This is a bat","this is the wicket"};
        int e=str.length;

        for(int j=0;j<e;j++)
        {
             String[] tokens = str[j].split("\\s");

             for( i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
             {
                 char capLetter = Character.toUpperCase(tokens[i].charAt(0));

                 toBeCapped +=  " " + capLetter + tokens[i].substring(1);
            }
            System.out.println(toBeCapped);
        }
    }
}
```

The output produced is as:-

```
This Is The Ball
This Is The Ball This Is The Bat
This Is The Ball This Is The Bat This Is The Wicket
```

I wanted the output to be as:-

```
This Is The Ball
This Is The 
This Is The Wicket
```

Please tell me what is the mistake I'm making. Thank You

Comment: You defined `toBeCapped` at the wrong scope. Move it three lines down, into the body of the outer `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you never reset `toBecapped` to `""` in the loop after printing.

Adding `toBeCapped=""` at the end of the loop after printing will fix this problem:

```
System.out.println(toBeCapped);
toBeCapped=""; // <<== Add this line
```

Note that string concatenation is relatively expensive in Java. A better approach is to use `StringBuilder`. [See this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15397515/335858) for an in-depth discussion of this topic.

Comment: Also a good idea to use a [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) if you are concatenating Strings.

Comment: `StringBuffer` is always a good idea to concatenate `Strings` as it gives less time complexity than the normal `String Concatenation.`

Comment: Thank You bro.Also I would like to ask you that how I can create this program using StringBuffer?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the problematic code. The `+=` appends the characters to an already built `toBeCapped` String. You need to set the `toBeCapped` String to an empty one after the innermost `for` loop

```
for( i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
{
  char capLetter = Character.toUpperCase(tokens[i].charAt(0));

  toBeCapped +=  " " + capLetter + tokens[i].substring(1);
}
System.out.println(toBeCapped);
}
toBeCapped = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a problem because `toBeCapped` variable is never reset after being used in the loop. A good coding practice is to declare and use loop variables inside the loop (not outside of it)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str[] ={"This is a ball","This is a bat","this is the wicket"};
  int e = str.length;

  for(int j=0;j<e;j++) {
    String toBeCapped="";
    String[] tokens = str[j].split("\\s");

    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
      char capLetter = Character.toUpperCase(tokens[i].charAt(0));
      toBeCapped +=  " " + capLetter + tokens[i].substring(1);
    }
    System.out.println(toBeCapped);
  }
}
```